# Help with new override for Except extension method

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write a new override of [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) extension method for `IEnumerable` which is able to take a comparer inline instead of using IEqualityComparer.

A, B are collections of a reference type..

Something like this:

```
A: [1, A], [2, A], [3, A]

B: [3, B], [4, B], [5, B]

C = A.Except(B, (a,b) => a.Id == b.Id);

C: [1, A], [2, A]
```

I wonder if you could help me with the code of the method.

```
public static class IEnumerableExntesion
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Except<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                        IEnumerable<T> second, 
                                        Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
        {

        }
    }
```

I was thinking of:

```
return source.Where (s => !second.Any(p => p.Id == s.Id));
```

But actually I couldn't convert it to a generic solution using the passed predicate!

Any help!

Comment: You could use Predicate<T, T> instead of Func<T, T, bool> - don't ask me why it has its own delegate type...

Comment: actualy predicate was introduced in .net 2 , and func was introduced in 3.5 its more accurate to use func from now on since there is no different at all between both , i think you should use the new LINQ Types as msdn recommend that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do the comparison using a predicate or can you use a projection instead and compare the projected values? If so then you could use some sort of `ExceptBy` method:

```
var c = a.ExceptBy(b, x => x.Id);

var r = p.ExceptBy(q, x => x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
    {
        if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
        if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");

        return first.ExceptByIterator(second, keySelector, keyComparer);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptByIterator<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer)
    {
        var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(second.Select(keySelector), keyComparer);

        foreach (TSource item in first)
        {
            if (keys.Add(keySelector(item)))
                yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this give me any benefits if I used it with LINQ to SQL ?

Comment: @John, I'm afraid not. A generic version of the `Any` query in your question should be exactly what you'd need (and I'd expect the LINQ-to-SQL provider to optimise that into performant SQL). Unfortunately, my expression tree/`IQueryable` skills aren't really up to that job!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
return source.Where(s => !second.Any(p => predicate(s, p))
```

Comment: Performance will be poor compared to the built-in `Except` implementation, but there's not really any other option if the OP needs to use a predicate rather than a projection.

Comment: @LukeH: No, the predicate was only a suggestion. Seems it's not the best one.

Answer (score 2):

```
return source.Where(s => !second.Any(p => predicate(p, s)));
```

Comment: Performance will be poor compared to the built-in `Except` implementation, but there's not really any other option if the OP needs to use a predicate rather than a projection.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use your passed `Func<T,T,bool>` to create a generic `IEqualityComparer` and pass it to regular `Except`:

```
public class PredicateEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _predicate;

    public PredicateEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _predicate(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T x)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Your extension method:

```
public static class IEnumerableExntesion
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Except<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                    IEnumerable<T> second, 
                                    Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Except(second, new PredicateEqualityComparer(predicate));
    }
}
```

Please note that I have stub `GetHashCode` implementation, it would be better to implement it properly but you would have to pass another delegate for it.

Comment: That `GetHashCode` implementation means that this probably won't perform any better than the other much simpler suggestions using `Any`.

Comment: What's wrong with using x.GetHashCode()? Then you rely on T to implement GetHashCode

Comment: @David: Because you are checking for equality by using an arbitrary predicate. The results of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` *must* be in sync with each other which means that `GetHashCode` somehow needs to know how the predicate works.

Comment: @Luke so, to be pendantically correct, you show have to pass in both an Equals and a GetHashCode deletegates? In which case you may as well implement IEqualityComparer<T>...